# How to change Text and Image color of button in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would love to change button color on click but have no idea how to access the color. I see that my button has component Image which includes that color however I am unable to access it. I have the same issue with button's text where I also didn't found a way how to access it.

I have tried follow [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-change-button-sprite-and-text-color.324741/) tutorial but I am getting error (more on screenshots).

```
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
//...
 // This is my onclick function
 public void SelectLevel(int level ) {
  Debug.Log(level);
  GameObject btn = GameObject.Find("Btn" + level);
  Debug.Log(btn);
  Image imgButton = btn.GetComponent<Image>();
  Debug.Log(imgButton);
 }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not the [UnityEngine.UIElements.Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Image.html) from the namespace

```
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
```

but rather [UnityEngine.UI.Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Image.html)

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my issue. VSCode doesn't recognise `UnityEngine.UI` in autocompletion there was only `UnityEngine.UIElements` available but code compiled without any issues if I used `UnityEngine.UI`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to change the color of the button:

```
btn.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
```

If you want a different color, remember to instantiate it like:

```
new Color(rValue,gValue,bValue);
```

And if you want to happens on onClick:

```
btn.onClick.AddListener(MethodToChangeColor);
```

Or with lambda expression:

```
btn.onClick.AddListener(() => { btn.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red; });
```

*Also check that your **Button700** has an Image component attached!!*

Comment: Thanks for help but issue was actually in the import I have used, it should have been `using UnityEngine.UI;` instead of `using UnityEngine.UIElements;`